# Dell C1100 flashing amber light, no video output

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, startup

I've been colocating a Dell Poweredge C1100 (CS24-TY) for over a year now, without any issues. The server was pulled out of a working environment and sent to my house, but when booted the server has no video output and the amber fault LED is flashing.

Made a few attempts of looking into the manuals - the drives seem fine. Stuck here.

EDIT: because the server is new to my network, I don't know the BMC IPs, and as it's not booting I'm unable to set the IPs.

The power light is solid and fault light is blinking, meaning "BMC critical condition event in power off mode (S0/S1)".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the boot output is being redirected to the COM1 port. This is an option in the C1100 BIOS. If you could attach an RS-232 type green screen VDU to the COM1 port and see if any output appears there. If you can then see the output and get into the BIOS and disable the redirection hopefully that would fix the problem.

Good luck!